# PHP 'move_uploaded_file' getting 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-413

When trying to upload a 130mb file I get 413 Request Entity Too Large. Using Network Solutions web hosting.

I've used .htaccess:

```
LimitRequestBody 10485760000
```

and php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 10000M
upload_max_filesize = 10000M
post_max_size = 10000M
```

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` to make sure these max size limits are actually set

Comment: What is your `.htaccess` configuration?

Comment: `LimitRequestBody` has an invalid value. The valid range is [from 0 (meaning unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

Comment: phpinfo shows post_max_size and upload_max_filesize as 10000M

Comment: Are you sure the server is Apache? not nginx or IIS, for example?

Comment: Should be Apache. I've got RewriteCond and RewriteRule. I've also tried removing my .htaccess configurations and leaving just LimitRequestBody.

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess file try to set the limit as

```
LimitRequestBody 150000000
```

Because as per apache server it should range between 0 - 2147483647(bytes).

This may solve your problem

**Refrence:** [Apache Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html)

And if then also its not working you need to set the `mod_reqtimeout` for apache 
modules as per your file and needs

You can refer it here [Apache Module mod_reqtimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html)

Comment: I've set the limit to 2147483647 but still getting 413 error

Comment: Is it a single file that you're trying to upload? or multiple files?

Comment: @Aziz yes that's a valid question .

Comment: a single 130mb file